# How to resolve symbols in separate template implementation file?

Tags: c++, templates, clion

I have a very simple question about the CLion IDE for which I wasn't able to find any help.

I have a header file (let's call it A.hpp) which declares a template class. The definitions of all the template class methods go into a separate file called A.ipp. The latter file is included at the of A.hpp. I think this is a pretty standard approach to keep your header files clean for template classes. The problem I face in CLion now is that none of the symbols in the A.ipp are resolved. I can understand that as A.ipp does NOT include A.hpp (but the other way around).

So my questions is whether there are some options to help CLion to resolve the symbols in A.ipp. Below is a very simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
// file: A.hpp

template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const T& d);
  void print() const;

private:
  T m_data;
};

#include "A.ipp"
```

and

```
// file: A.ipp

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(const T& d):
  m_data(d)
{}

template<typename T>
void Foo<T>::print() const {
  std::cout << m_data << std::endl;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Can you provide some code please, I find it hard to follow on this abstract level.

Comment: While [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4406) is not resolved, you can include your .hpp file on top of the .ipp as a workaround. During the actual compilation it won't be included twice because of include guards/pragma once.

Comment: @JanHenke: Sorry, for not including an example. I added one now.

Comment: @goldwin-es: Thanks for the pointer to the issue. So I guess we will have to wait until this is fixed. While including the header file solves the problem, I am not really happy about it. We fight hard to reduce the number of includes in our code. So adding one just to make the IDE happy does not feel right. The IDE should help the developer, not the other way around.